# Responsive in React Native

Tags: react-native

For example I have a View with styll: width:100, height:100 for the screen with resolution ~160DPI
But if the app built on a device with DPI around 320, the View would be to small on the screen
So what is the solution for this?
How to make the styles the app automatically change depend on the size of the device?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `react-native-responsive-screen`
is a great package for making a responsive layout
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen

or you can simply calculate

```
import { PixelRatio } from 'react-native';
PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel()
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio.html

```
import { Dimensions, PixelRatio } from 'react-native';
let Width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
let Height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const wp = widthPercent => {
  const elemWidth = typeof widthPercent === "number" ? widthPercent : parseFloat(widthPercent);
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenWidth * elemWidth / 100);
};

const hp = heightPercent => {
  const elemHeight = typeof heightPercent === "number" ? heightPercent : parseFloat(heightPercent);

  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenHeight * elemHeight / 100);
};
```

and use as

```
<View style={{height: hp(10), width: wp(20)}} >
  <Text style={{fontSize: hp(3.4)}} />
</View>
```

**hp** Height percentage

**wp** Width percentage

Comment: can you share some example? and how to use the PixelRatio please?

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can make a separate file and can change implementation as your need